# Can not close my http connection from java to ASP.Net server

Tags: java, asp.net, httpurlconnection, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a java application that pushes a message to a bunch of urls. These ulrs are of different server types, like apache, IIS, ... .

Now I need to send this message to each url. If the Url reponds to me everything is ok and if they didn't (until a specific timeout) I want to close the connection anyway. So I used CloseableHttpClient for this purpose.

my code is as below:

```
public void pushToURL(Message message, String url, int notifierId) throws NotificationException, IOException {
    long responseTime;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setConnectionRequestTimeout(this.socketTimeOut)
            .setSocketTimeout(this.socketTimeOut)
            .setConnectTimeout(this.socketTimeOut)
            .build();

    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig)
                    .setConnectionReuseStrategy(NoConnectionReuseStrategy.INSTANCE)
                    .build();

    URIBuilder builder = null;


    try {
        builder = new URIBuilder(url);
        builder = builder.addParameter("msgBody", receivedMessage.getMsgBody());
        builder = builder.addParameter("receivedTime", String.valueOf(receivedMessage.getReceivedTime()));

        URI uri = builder.build();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
        logMaster.debug(className, "notifier #" + notifierId + ": Try Sending notification to httpserver: " + url + " receivedTime:" + message.getReceivedTime());
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (code < 300) {
            logMaster.debug(className, "notifier #" + notifierId + ": Notification to httpserver sent: code:" + code + " url:" + url + " receivedTime:" + message.getReceivedTime() + ", Executed in " + responseTime + " milliSec");
            if (response != null)
                httpGet.abort();
            return;
        } else {
            if (response != null)
                httpGet.abort();
            logMaster.info(className, "notifier #" + notifierId + ": Sending notification failed. Http response error");
            throw new NotificationException("Sending notification failed. Http response error");
        }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, URISyntaxException, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, ClientProtocolException, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, ConnectTimeoutException, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, InterruptedIOException, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, UnknownHostException, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, IOException, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logMaster.warn(className, "Notification problem, " + e.getMessage() + ", to:" + url + ", in:" + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime) + " milliseconds. notifierId: " + notifierId);
        throw new NotificationException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        // Release the connection.
        httpClient.close();
        logMaster.debug(className, "notifier " + notifierId + " closed the httpClient. " +
                "url: " + url + " receivedTime:" + message.getReceivedTime());

    }


}
```

There are 10 threads that use this function to send the message to urls.

In some situations that I DON'T KNOW, there are urls that I can not close the connection by force(actually after timeOut). Everything that I know is that these URLs are ASP.net ones and just sometimes do such that. It is like that I create a connection to them and even by force I can not close the connection !!!

It's so strange and kept my work for more than a week. I searched about many solutions but no one helped. Is there anyone who can help with the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Close your response too, that maybe make the trick. If that does not work,  you can change the way you create the connection, and use a connection manager. In the next url you can find some useful examples: [example](http://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-connection-management)